# SQL query to get count of records on previous updated date (not latest update) and group by certain column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table T

```
SELECT country, count(*) ,max(upated_date) from T
GROUP BY country
```

This will give me count of records and latest update date by country.
How to get count of records on previous latest updated date by country?
note: updated date is different for each country

basically I want like this

[image: table]

Comment: "country wise count of records on latest update date" apparently it doesn't. This returns total number of rows and  latest update date by country.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the second last update date, then use window functions:

```
SELECT country, count(*),
       max(updated_date),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then updated_date end) as penultimate_updated_date
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY updated_date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM T
     ) t
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff , I updated question with desired output . Please check